# unable to authenticate with mongodb golang driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-go-driver

I'm using mongodb community version 4.2.13 and go driver version 1.5.

My go application is running on the same host as db, but getting the following error when trying to make a connection:

```
connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error:
sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism
"SCRAM-SHA-256": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Here is how I created the admin account:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "admin1",
  pwd: "passwd12#$",
  roles: ["root"],
  mechanisms: ["SCRAM-SHA-256"]
})

db.system.users.update(
  { _id: "admin.admin1", "db": "admin" },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      authenticationRestrictions: { clientSource: ["127.0.0.1"] }
    }
  }
)
```

Go app code snippet

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    uri := fmt.Sprintf(
        "mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/admin?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256",
        "admin1",
        "passwd12#$",
        "127.0.0.1",
        27017,
    )
 
    // Prints "mongodb://admin1:passwd12#$@127.0.0.1:27017/admin?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256"
    fmt.Println(uri)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10 * time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(
        ctx,
        options.Client().ApplyURI(uri),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        err = client.Disconnect(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("pinged")
}
```

I tried the following, but all of them didn't work:

- Encoding username and password using `url.QueryEscape`
- Trying "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"
- Removing "authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256" in uri

As a side note, connecting to the Mongo shell with the exact same uri, and that worked.

Comment: I am not familiar with go, perhaps you have to escape the $ dollar sign in your password.

Comment: Did you try to remove the 'authenticationRestrictions'? I would assume you have to put your real IP address, not the loopback IP

Comment: See the server log for the error.

Comment: Note that the proper way to add an authentication restriction is to include it in the object passed to [createUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#db-createuser) or [updateUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.updateUser/#db-updateuser).  Not sure if those make a difference or not.

Comment: I figured it out. I looked at the log as @D. SM suggested, and it said 2021-03-21T15:22:25.768+0900 I  ACCESS   [conn102] Failed to acquire user 'admin1@admin' because of unmet authentication restrictions: Restriction '{anyOf: [{allOf: [{"clientSource": ["127.0.0.1/32"]}]}]}' in '{allOf: [{anyOf: [{allOf: [{"clientSource": ["127.0.0.1/32"]}]}]}]}' unmet" I guess the db thinks the go app's source ip is illegal cuz it's "127.0.0.1/32", not "127.0.0.1". Now I'm investigating 1) Why this happens only with the go driver 2) How can I make all IPs of the form "127.0.0.1/*" be accepted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ssl=false` to your uri. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You could try using 'options.Credential' to pass the authentication settings.

Seems like a cleaner way than formatting an URI that needs to be parsed later on.

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/auth/

```
clientOpts := options.Client().SetHosts(
    []string{"localhost:27017"},
).SetAuth(
    options.Credential{
        AuthSource: "<authenticationDb>",
        AuthMechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-256",
        Username: "<username>",
        Password: "<password>",
    }
)
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on MongoDB documentation for the authentication process, there is a parameter to identify which database is used for authentication besides the target database on the URI.

While in mongoshell you can use this line

```
mongo "mongodb://Admin:${DBPASSWORD}@<host>:<port>/admin?authSource=admin"
```

I used that information to add `?authSource=admin` to my CONNECTION_URL

```
CONNECTION_URL=mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/my_database?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin
```

That worked for me. Hope it does for you too.

For detailed information please review https://www.mongodb.com/features/mongodb-authentication